# Facebook friend list Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-friends

In my own app, i ask users friend facebook friend list. This allows me to display a list of user's facebook friends that also use my app. However Ive encountered some error with MY OWN facebook account. If i log in to my app with other facebook accounts, there are no issues, the friend list appears...but using my own facebook account, the friend list is blank. Ive made sure to check facebook permissions, ive removed them, added them again, deleted my account from app then re logged in etc...nothing helps.

Im 90% sure its an issue with my facebook, not the app itself because again, all other fb accounts that ive logged in with work no problem. Is there some setting in facebook that I might not have tried yet that may be messing up my ability to see my friend list within the app?

Comment: What programming language are you referring to?

Comment: I'll check with my developer to confirm but I believe objective c...but again I dont believe its an issue with the app as all other facebook accounts work no problem...there is something in my facebook settings that doesnt allow me to use the friend list that ive allowed permissions for

Comment: can anyone else help?